# python sqlalchemy exist & select 'next' syntax

Tags: python, mysql, syntax, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm trying to implement

```
NOT EXIST (SELECT 'NEXT' FROM ... )
```

in python sqlalchemy and is having trouble figure out the SELECT 'NEXT' syntax.  I did find there is a `next_value()` in sql [next_value](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_8/core/functions.html#sqlalchemy.sql.functions.next_value)

Ive tried

```
~exist(next_value()).where(...)
```

but `next_value()` is not defined.  What may the proper syntax be?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
from sqlalchemy.sql import func
# ...    
~exist(func.next_value()).where(...)
```